# iOS universal linking: exlude naked domain only

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to support Universal Links in my iOS app.

I would like the `mydomain.com/` url to be excluded from Universal Link support, that is, to always open a webpage when url is tapped from an iOS device.

And I'd like `mydomain.com/sometext` url to open the linked app if it's installed.

Does anyone know if such requirements can be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working configuration!

The `path` value needs to be

`"paths": [ "NOT /", "/*" ]`